# 2-Manifold an image of the unit disc?

Tags: differential-topology, manifolds

Is every 2 dimensional manifold whose boundary is a cycle, a continuous image of the unit disc? Maybe it happens if the space is good enough? I wanted to prove an equality between two definitions I've seen to simply-connectedness. (Every continuous image the circle is null homotopic, and every cycle is a boundary of another manifold). I also want to know if the vice versa holds: if any continuous image of the unit disc is a manifold.
Please keep in mind I don't have a lot of knowledge on the subject. I wasn't sure about which tags I should add to this question. Thanks!

Comment: Robert Israel has answered the question you asked, but I expect it is not exactly the question you wanted to ask. If you remove an open disk from a torus, you are left with a two manifold with a circle for a boundary. It is evidently not simply connected; it is not a topological disk.

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18083/is-every-compact-n-manifold-a-compactification-of-mathbbrn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any  compact, connected, locally connected second-countable Hausdorff space (in particular any compact connected manifold with boundary) is a continuous image of the unit interval, and thus of the unit disk.  See the Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem.

Comment: Thanks. For the equality of the definitions I also need the other way around: To show that any continuous image of the disc is a manifold. I'm not sure if it's true because of the extra differential structure I'm not sure a continuous function preserves...

Comment: No, of course it isn't true.  It's very easy to construct counterexamples.

Comment: Then how every image of the circle is null homotopic => every cycle is a boundary?